# "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" error while trying to save entity to bd

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am trying to update entitys in asynchronous way. Thats how my update method looks like

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateEntityAsync<T>(IDbContext source, T entity) where T : class 
{
    try
    {
        source.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; // here I get error
        await source.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my Interface IDbContext

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T: class;

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();

    DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

and I am calling method UpdateEntityAsync from button click

```
public async override void ButtonClick(object sender)
{
    ComboboxSelectedValue.IsValid = 0;

    var result = await ViewModel.Instance.Repository.UpdateEntityAsync(new Entities(), ComboboxSelectedValue);
    if (result)
    {
        StatusBarText = "Changed";
        return;
    }
    StatusBarText = "Some error, record's state not changed!";
}
```

So error says *An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*, but I send new instance, so I don't really understand why I get this error and how to solve this issue. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I bet this happens the *second* time you press the button...?

Comment: It happens also when I press first time

Comment: Did you load Entities in the context before this?

Comment: Yes, I am loading values (to show information on the form) and save them to observableCollection. This collection I bind to combobox. And after ButtonClick was pressed, I want to set IsValid to 0 for selected value and save changes to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find a solution.
I've changed IDbContext to

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T: class;

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();

    void MarkAsModified<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

Then implemented MarkAsModified:

```
public void MarkAsModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

and now my UpdateEntityAsync looks like

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateEntityAsync<T>(IDbContext source, T entity) where T : class 
{
    try
    {
        source.MarkAsModified(entity);
        await source.SaveChangesAsync();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help somebody.